# Adding Text overlay to my Vimeo Full Screen Background -iframe-

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, video

Currently I am working on a full video background setup.  This is a newbie question.  I want to add text over the video.   I Did search on here for some tutorials and tried a few things but just could not get it to work.

Code:

```
<div class="video"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="540"            mozallowfullscreen="" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99315264? title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=3a6774&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="960"></iframe>


    <style type="text/css">body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
     }
    .Video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%}


     .Video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .Video .Overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    }
    </style>
```

The code is working perfect however I wanted to add some text overlay.   I have been reading tutorials however I just cannot seem to find the right fit.  Easy question I am sure.  Thank you for your help.

Also when using this format

example:

```
 <video autoplay loop>
 <source src=”loop.mp4” type=”video/mp4”>
 <source src=”loop.webm” type=”video/webm”>
 <source src=”loop.ogv” type=”video/ogg”>
 </video>
```

the vimeo video did no load correctly- 404 error- so I used the iframe setup instead-- seems to be the trick.  I am using the Vimeo video because I have a paid account which allows me to customize the video settings and play it in full HD.

Thanks again.

my video http://lmdesigns.x10host.com/Designtest.html

Comment: Fullscreen video cannot show other elements unless included in the fullscreen wrapper too. So instead of making the video fullscreen, make the whole wrapper fullscreen.

Comment: Use higher z-index such as 999 it will solve your problem.@user3784332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a div to absolute, and from there position it inside of the container div with a higher z-index than the video element.

```
.text-div {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 97px;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 3; 
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code for the overall video setup

```
  <style>
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe,
.videoWrapper embed,
.videoWrapper object {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
    </style>
    <div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99315264?    title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=3a6774&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="500%" height="291%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

worked perfect.   Now moving on to the text.  Very fun project I appreciate your inputs.  It is funny because there was a lot of different ways to do this with code.  Was a task trying to find the right way.

http://lmdesigns.x10host.com/Designtest.html

Comment: oh and the dreaded Vimeo play/pause button.  Final Project will have a icon or graphic over it :p